# Weird type inference in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, type-inference

I have some trouble with Scala type inference.
In following worksheet example I have defined a Map which maps Any values to a function returning a Unit value.

Interestingly, when I try to define the same map using only one line of code it doesn't work because the 'bar' functions return-type suddenly changes to Any instead of Unit.

```
type UnitFun = (Any) => Unit

val foo = "foo"
val bar = (a: Any) => System.out.println("bar")

val map: Map[Any, UnitFun] = Map().withDefaultValue(((a: Any) => Unit))
val doesCompile: Map[Any, UnitFun] = map + (foo -> bar)

val doesNotCompile: Map[Any, UnitFun] = Map().withDefaultValue(((a: Any) => Unit)) + (foo -> bar)
```

I am using IDEA14 as IDE with Scala 2.11.6

It seems to me like this is a Feature/Bug of the Scala compiler, or am I missing something?

btw I've just noticed that when I use 'bar' as default value in 'doesNotCompile' like this:

```
val doesCompileNow: Map[Any, UnitFun] = Map().withDefaultValue(bar) + (foo -> bar)
```

it suddenly seems to work, I am pretty baffled right now. :D

Edit 1:
@Mikolak

In this case, how does the following code works? :)

```
val a: Any => Unit = (a: Any) => Unit
val b: Any => Unit = (a: Any) => ()
```

Shouldn't both expressions be of a different type? Or is there some implicit type conversion involved?

Comment: Added explanation regarding your edit. Note that this is a phenomenon that's completely orthogonal to the original one.

Comment: Already seen it, I think the implicit conversion from **Unit.type** to **Any** (according to intellij output) is what lead me off track on this one. I assume it is just another impicit conversion. :)

Comment: One thing to add then: **do not trust** IntelliJ's syntax checking. While slowly getting better, it still has a propensity to output both false positives and false negatives. In other words, your first course of action when you get a weird error should be to run `sbt compile`.

Comment: I now know I made a mistake by using 'Unit' instead of '()' but still it is interesting to see that depending on how I write my Code those implicit conversions result in a different type (very first piece of code). ^^

Comment: Yeah, that's the price to pay when the language has typing that's both strong and unobtrusive - in corner cases like these you're bound to obtain seemingly unintuitive results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Original compile error

The compile error happens because this function:

```
(a: Any) => Unit
```

is of type

```
Any => Unit.type
```

and **not** of type:

```
Any => Unit
```

In other words, you are returning [`Unit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.Unit$), the **companion object of the `Unit` type**. That companion object has a type `Unit.type`, which is a **different** type than `Unit` (this applies to all companion objects in Scala).

What you need is to actually return a value of type `Unit`. [As outlined in the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.Unit), **the only such value is `()`**.

So, your default function should be: `(a: Any) => ()`.

---

**EDIT:** Regarding the supplementary question.

## Conversion to Unit

Here:

```
val a: Any => Unit = (a: Any) => Unit
```

you are explicitly typing the expression to have a return type of `Unit`. Normally it would result in a type error, but (as you suspect) "fortunately" **you triggered [one of the pre-defined implicit value conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions)**, specifically :

> Value Discarding
>
> If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.

So, this:

```
(a: Any) => Unit  //return type is Unit.type
```

becomes:

```
(a: Any) => {Unit; ();} //return type is Unit
```

Note that as per the definition, the conversion applies to any value, so e.g. `val c: Unit = "c"` produces the same result.